# R: Downloading, Unzipping and Saving Files From the Internet to the Temporary Directory

Tags: r, csv

I am working with the R programming language.

I am trying to write an R script to download a folder, unzip this folder and then import the csv file into R.

- **main webpage:** https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2021/dp-pd/prof/details/download-telecharger.cfm?Lang=E
- **folder to be downloaded:** https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2021/dp-pd/prof/details/download-telecharger/comp/GetFile.cfm?Lang=E&FILETYPE=CSV&GEONO=012
- **csv file name (I think):** 98-401-X2021012_English_CSV_data.csv

In particular, since this is a big file - **I am trying to write some code that will save this csv to the "temporary directory" such that it will be automatically deleted when I restart my computer.**

Here is the address to my temp directory:

```
> tempfile()
[1] "C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpMzoYjA\\file4d2c5123acd"
```

I tried to use the following code for this problem:

```
# Set the URL of the zipped CSV file
url <- "https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2021/dp-pd/prof/details/download-telecharger/comp/GetFile.cfm?Lang=E&FILETYPE=CSV&GEONO=012"

# Set the path for the temporary file
temp_file_path <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")

# Download the file from the URL and save it to the temporary file
download.file(url, destfile = temp_file_path, mode = "wb")

# Unzip the file to the temporary directory
temp_dir <- tempdir()
unzip(temp_file_path, exdir = temp_dir)
```

After running this code, I then wanted to see the contents of the  temporary folder:

```
> list.files(temp_dir)
[1] "98-401-X2021012_English_CSV_data.csv"             "98-401-X2021012_English_meta.txt"                 "98-401-X2021012_Geo_starting_row.CSV"            
[4] "README_meta.txt"                                  "rs-graphics-a29a9849-423f-45db-8310-475e45964e33"
```

Based on these results, I then tried to import the desired csv file into R:

```
test <- read.csv(file.path(temp_dir, "98-401-X2021012_English_CSV_data.csv"))
```

**Can someone please tell me if I am doing this correctly?**

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like reading in the data should work. Does it not? Your only problem is you're unzipping to the temp folder so when the cache is cleared you'll lose the unzipped data as well as the zip file.

Comment: I am not seeing nothing wrong with your code, are there any errors or warnings?

Comment: Thanks everyone! Just wanted to make sure I was doing everything correctly (e.g. making sure that the file is being saved to the temporary directory and not the permanent directory)